# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'intuitlib'

Tags: python, pycharm, intuit-partner-platform

When I run the following code in PyCharm the 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'intuitlib'' error occurs

```
from intuitlib.client import AuthClient
```

I installed intuit-oauth seemingly successfully with pip3

```
% pip3 install intuit-oauth
```

I am using Python 3.11.4 and pip 23.2.1

VERY VERY new at this, this is my first question ever so please bear with me

Comment: check with `pip3 list`if the module is really installed.

Comment: thank you. I ran     pip3 list and intuit-oauth is installed

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using the correct python. You may have installed the package in the python of your IDE, but you are running the code with the system python.

The VENV python is saved with a name next to it, as in the example below:

[IDE Python example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKl9K.png)

Comment: Usually the operating system python is the one without any identification on the side.

Comment: that was indeed the issue. It looks like the package was installed on the system python and I was running different python on the IDE. I installed from git on IDE python and now working. Thank you vm @Falkat!! Last question @falkat how to I recognize you for your helpful answer on SO?

Comment: just click on "This answer is useful" and we'll be fine.